# Adding -ObjC to other linker flag shows "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus, linker-errors

In my app, a user can login via Google Plus. I have integrated Google Plus to my App. I've integrated GooglePlus several times before without any issue.

But this time when I try to add '-ObjC' to other linker flags in targets, it shows
"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

If i remove -ObjC from other linker flags it working properly but GPPSignInButton is not working and it shows 'Unknown class GPPSignInButton in Interface Builder file' in console

In the current App that I am making, there is a UDPEchoClient. Could that be the problem or is it something else? Please help

this is the error showing

ld: 41 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 Ld /Users/sw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UdpEchoClient-emymmgqsyfcsrfbmlqdweqfyccqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UdpEchoClient.app/UdpEchoClient normal armv7

Comment: Show the build command line that failed.

Comment: ld: 41 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: No I'd like to see the command line being invoked by Xcode.  You'll find it in the log viewer.

Comment: Ld /Users/switch/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UdpEchoClient-emymmgqsyfcsrfbmlqdweqfyccqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UdpEchoClient.app/UdpEchoClient normal armv7
    cd /Users/switch/Desktop/CocoaAsyncSocket-master/GCD/Xcode/UdpEchoClient/Mobile
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Comment: Please edit your question and delete that comment.  That command line is also incomplete.

Comment: if i keep any thing in other linker flags in targets it shows this error

Comment: Does it say what the duplicate symbols its seeing are? Its probably just a case of having two versions of lib somewhere (or a lib and the source for it both included).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing framworks in project.
As per [Getting Started with the Google+ Platform for iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) You need to include the following frameworks in your Xcode project:

- AddressBook.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- Foundation.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- CoreMotion.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreText.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- Security.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- UIKit.framework

Drag and drop the following frameworks from the SDK into your XCode project:

- GooglePlus.framework
- GoogleOpenSource.framework

Comment: If you have used -all_load flag than remove it and try

Comment: if i keep any thing in other linker flags it shows this error

Comment: In your code you have two different files with the same Interface name.

Comment: Check import files, may be you import m file.

Comment: May be you have added #import "ABC.m" file instead of "ABC.h"

Comment: i have check through out the app i have not imported .m file anywhere.

Comment: use $(inherited) flag in OtherLinker flag

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cocoa pods , then you have to Drag and drop the following frameworks from the SDK into your XCode project's  'link binary with libraries' section

GooglePlus.framework
GoogleOpenSource.framework